# ArcPy ArcGIS Basic Standard: Get symmetric difference with partially contained, uneven numbers of polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, symmetric-difference

I already looked up topics for rewriting the erase and symmetric difference functions, but I don't get it running.

I got the following situation:
[image: My Input]
FC1 and FC2 are my polygon input feature classes. FC1 consists of two polygons, FC2 only of one. I want following output:
[image]
So I want two feature class outputs: OUT1 and OUT2, which looks pretty much like a symmetric difference. So I did `arcpy.Union_analysis((FC1,FC2), union)`. After this I worked with `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(union, "CONTAINS_CLEMENTINI", FC1, "", "NEW_SELECTION")` (also tried "CONTAINS"), but this gives me an empty output feature class after executing `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(union, FC1_only)`. Normally I would proceed with `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(union, "", "", "", "SWITCH_SELECTION")` and then already get OUT2. Why does this not work? And is this a right way to rewrite the Erase function only available for Advanced ArcGIS?

**EDIT**:
Ok, instead of going with the `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management` stuff, I used the `arcpy.Select_analysis` on the union output with the `query = '"FID_fc1" > -1 AND "FID_fc2" > -1'`. Now I got the purple part shown above.
What is the best way to get two separate feature classes, one with the leftovers of fc1 and one with the leftovers of fc2?

**EDIT2**:
This is the code I have so far... I thought of maybe replacing the search cursor with an update cursor and handling the feature class output while still in the Loop by deleting the rows I don't want.... or do I have to create two queries? One with `FID_fc1 > -1 AND FID_fc2 = -1` and one with `FID_fc1 = -1 AND FID_fc2 > -1` ?

```
 elif desc.shapeType == "Polygon":
        # Initiate variables
        poly_union = outputFolder + "poly_union.shp"
        select_poly = outputFolder + "select_poly.shp"
        fid1 = ""
        fid2 = ""
        # Perform union on both polygon inputs
        arcpy.Union_analysis([new_data,old_data], poly_union)
        # Get the names of the FID fields for building the query later on
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(poly_union, ["NAME", "NAME_1"]) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                # If the NAME field is empty, just do nothing
                if row[0] == "" or row[0] == " ":
                    pass
                else:
                    # Use the name for building the FID_ field name
                    fid1 = "FID_{0}".format(row[0][0:6])
                # If the NAME_1 field is empty, just do nothing
                if row[1] == "" or row[1] == " ":
                    pass
                else:
                    # Check for the same names for the polygons to get correct FID_ field names
                    if row[0][0:6] == row[1][0:6]:
                        fid2 = "FID_{0}_1".format(row[1][0:4])
                    else:
                        fid2 = "FID_{0}".format(row[1][0:6])
        # Build the query with the extracted FID_ field names
        query = '"{0}" > -1 AND "{1}" > -1'.format(fid1,fid2)
        # Perform selection of the intersection of the polygons
        arcpy.Select_analysis(poly_union, select_poly, query)
        # ToDo: Delete intersection to get symmetric difference and output 2 feature classes
```

Comment: To select the overlap, after Union, can't you select FID_fc1 > -1 and FID_fc2 > -1. You will then Delete these Polygons because  they represent the overlap between the feature classes.

Comment: @klewis I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @klewis ok, i executed following query `'"FID_fc1" > -1 AND "FID_fc2" > -1'` (ArcMap told me all the time that the query was invalid, but Catalog told me that the error was elsewhere and when I fixed it, ArcMap suddenly accepted the query ... strange) The result now is only the intersecting area, how should I "delete" this now to get two separate Feature class outputs with the non-intersecting areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got a working version... the whole trick was using the FID_ fields created by the `Union_analysis` function to build two queries. Each of the queries then selects one whole input feature but without every intersection. This is only possible, because the `Union_analysis` function creates separate polygons for the intersection areas.

```
elif desc.shapeType == "Polygon":
    # Initiate variables
    poly_union = outputFolder + "poly_union.shp"
    select_poly = outputFolder + "select_poly.shp"
    old_filename = basename(old_data)
    new_filename = basename(new_data)
    # Perform union on both polygon inputs
    arcpy.Union_analysis([new_data,old_data], poly_union)
    # Get the names of the FID fields for building the query later on
    fid1 = "FID_{0}".format(old_filename[0:6])
    fid2 = ""
    if old_filename[0:6] == new_filename[0:6]:
        fid2 = "FID_{0}_1".format(new_filename[0:4])
    else:
        fid2 = "FID_{0}".format(new_filename[0:6])
    # Remove old things that dont intersect
    query_only_new = '"{0}" > -1 AND "{1}" = -1'.format(fid1,fid2)
    arcpy.Select_analysis(poly_union, select_poly, query_only_new)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(select_poly, new_diffs)
    # Remove new things that dont intersect
    query_only_old = '"{0}" = -1 AND "{1}" > -1'.format(fid1,fid2)
    arcpy.Select_analysis(poly_union, select_poly, query_only_old)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(select_poly, old_diffs)
```